# How to parameterize ports for docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, parameterization

I am trying to parameterize a docker-compose file using `.env`. [Doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution)

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.3'
networks:
    default: { external: true, name: $NETWORK_NAME }
services:
    rabbitmq_local:
        image: 'rabbitmq:3.6-management-alpine'
        ports:
          # The standard AMQP protocol port
          - ${RABBIT_PORT}:5672
          # HTTP management UI
          - '15672:15672'
```

.env file

```
NETWORK_NAME=uv_atp_network
RABBIT_PORT=5672
RABBIT_HTTP_MANAGEMENT_PORT=15672
```

Parameterizing `NETWORK_NAME` works, but parameterizing `RABBIT_PORT` doesn't, with

```
The Compose file 'docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.rabbitmq_local.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
```

This makes me suspect `RABBIT_PORT` is interpreted as string rather than a number.

How can I parameterize it correctly?

---

EDIT

I found that forcing the variable to be mandatory

```
- ${RABBIT_PORT:?unspecified_rabbit_port}:5672
```

gives the error, meaning it is unset or empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `docker-compose config` to see a valid output after replacing variables with actual value. I think either your docker-compose binary is of older version (mine is 1.26.) or your files has some invalid chars. I tried with above config and got correct output.

Comment: @fly2matrix I am using 1.24 (and can't go above because of unrelated reasons). Why is it relevant here?

Comment: try it here : https://labs.play-with-docker.com/p/c7smfsfnjsv00092mv4g#c7smfsfn_c7smg37njsv00092mv5g

Comment: @fly2matrix Try what?

Comment: Above link that I shared has the same settings docker-compose.yml and env

Comment: Link that I shared is a session on play-with-docker that is valid for 3 hours only. So you can check by yourself - if your configs are technically correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when running with [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.0.x/) and [pytest-docker-compose](https://github.com/pytest-docker-compose/pytest-docker-compose#:%7E:text=This%20package%20contains%20a%20pytest,down%20after%20each%20test%20ends.) the `.env` file has to be in the root folder of `pytest`, along with the `pytest.ini` file.

Running from docker-compose from command-line doesn't have that limitation in docker 1.24.

After relocating the file, the variables could be resolved.